# rsync: excluding a directory from the source

Tags: rsync

It appears in the code below, `rsync` ignores `--exclude`. How would I correct that, and extend it to multiple directories?

```
$ rsync --help | grep Usage
Usage: rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... DEST

$ man rsync | grep -- '--exclude'
   --exclude=PATTERN        exclude files matching PATTERN

$ sudo rsync -avz --exclude='/home/erwann/.cache/' '/home/erwann' '/run/media/erwann/bkup'
sending incremental file list
erwann/.cache/mozilla/firefox/otj9do4j.default-release/cache2/
erwann/.cache/mozilla/firefox/otj9do4j.default-release/cache2/index
erwann/.cache/mozilla/firefox/otj9do4j.default-release/cache2/doomed/
erwann/.cache/mozilla/firefox/otj9do4j.default-release/cache2/entries/
```

Comment: Exclude pattern matching matches from the start directory. Correct would be `sudo rsync -avz --exclude='erwann/.cache/' '/home/erwann' '/run/media/erwann/bkup'` to extend it to multiple dirs, either work with pattern-matchin in the exclude or take a look at --exclude-from

Comment: @stoney case closed.

Comment: @stoney Note that your example would also hide `/home/erwann/.cache/erwann/.cache`, if that directory existed.

Comment: @Kusalananda i guess that is what he wanted. or did you mean `/home/erwann/whatever/erwann/.cache`?

Comment: @stoney Yes, that's what I meant. Any `erwann/.cache` directory beneath the source path.

Comment: Point to you ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patterns consider the bit of the pathname that *isn't* part of the source path.  This means that to match the directory `.cache` *directly* under the source path `/home/erwann`, you would use `/erwann/.cache/` as the pattern (since the `/home` directory is what `rsync` uses as "transfer-root"):

```bash
rsync -av --exclude=/erwann/.cache/ /home/erwann /run/media/erwann/bkup
```

By anchoring the exclusion pattern at the top of the path with `/` at the start, we avoid matching it in lower parts of the file hierarchy.

If you add `/` at the end of the source path, `/home/erwann` becomes the "transfer-root", and the pattern can therefore be shortened into `/.cache/`.  However, we now also have to *add* `erwann` to the destination path to get the same effect as before:

```bash
rsync -av --exclude=/.cache/ /home/erwann/ /run/media/erwann/bkup/erwann
```

From the `rsync` manual:

> If you think of the
> transfer as a subtree of names that are being sent from sender to
> receiver, the transfer-root is where the tree starts to be duplicated
> in the destination directory.  This root governs where patterns that
> start with a `/` match.

Comment: @Erwann Make sure the individual patterns in the brace expansion are quoted. Make sure that there is no whitespace after the commas in the brace expansion.